# Devise Reset Password POSTs instead of PUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using a non customized version of Devise in my app and am running into some issues with the reset password functionality.

The default reset password form's method is to PUT but upon submitting the form, it POSTs which causes it to give me an error about a missing email field. The POST/create method in the PasswordsController of Devise is emailing the user the password reset link. The PUT/update method is for the actual resetting of the password.

None of the devise stuff is altered in any way. Devise version is 3.5.7 and Rails is 4.2.6

I've put all of the relevant code in a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/dsarhadian/a7950e480bffc2906f77b0e542792f5a

Any help is truly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

In your logs it says:
`Rendered devise/passwords/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms)`

Are you sure that the edit.html.erb file renders the `form.html.erb` view?
Because when I look at the `source.html` file, it seems like it is rendering a different form which has the path for the POST method.
The `form.html.erb` uses the PUT method. So it seems to me like the wrong form is rendered.

Comment: edit.html.erb and form.html.erb are the same thing. (I updated the gist to reflect that). What happens is that when the form POSTs it goes to the new.html.erb form.

Comment: what worries me is that the edit.html.erb and source.html are not the same. If you are rendering the edit.html.erb, then the source.html.erb should have the method to be PUT (check line 17 of source.html). Are you rendering edit.html.erb?

Comment: I read a lot of the rails docs and it says it's supposed to put method="post". Rails then generates a hidden input like so: <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />. Then rails *should* use the PUT method. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark

Comment: Looking at your rake routes, line 2-6. The post method will map to the create action (which is not what you want if I understand correctly). What you want is the update action, which corresponds to the PUT method.

Comment: It's weird because it is calling the create action instead of the update action. The reason why it is asking for the missing email field is because it is what the new.html.erb form requires.

Comment: Exactly! I've seen others report this same issue with Devise, but I can't seem to find a fix

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? I'm running into the exactly same issue